# Decryption : How to secure the Key in offline mode

Tags: keys, key-exchange, decryption

I am new to cryptography.

I have a package to be shared with *Bob* which is something like below:

```
Package contains: data.zip and Application
```

where,

- data.zip is encrypted
- Application will have logic to decrypt the data

*Bob* will run `Application` and it will decrypt the `data.zip`.

> Now for the decryption key, I understand that I can maintain a key store
> where I can keep the key securely which my Application will access and
> get the key.

But in my case *Bob* will execute the `Application` offline.

Building the `Application` with the decryption key doesn't make sense as *Bob* can easily take the key or logic to form the key from `Application`.

In this scenario how can I handle the decryption part? what is the ideal solution and how where should I keep the key?

Comment: Congratulation, you correctly identified a limitation of crypto: decryption requires a secret, and it needs to be stored safely. I'm sorry that we only have limited options for this. Some of the best involve hardware: Smart Card, HSM, TPM. Others involve Bob memorizing a passphrase/password and keying it in. There are hybrids (e.g. One Time Password generator with a PIN). And then biometry can be thrown in the mix. It would help if you limited your scope. And I'm not sure the question will end on-topic for crypto-SE; have you thought of [security-SE](https://security.stackexchange.com/)?